# Problems with exceptions

Tags: python

I'm trying to do an exercise on Python. For this, I have to use the following function:

```
def getNumber() :
    x = input ('Choose a number: ')
    if x == 17:      
        raise ("ErrorBadNumber","17 is a bad number")
    return x
```

The exercise says create another function that uses `getNumber` and handle the exception `ErrorBadNumber`.

I've created the function `getNumber_2` to try solve the exercise:

```
def getNumber() :
    x = input ('Choose a number: ')
    if x == 17:      
        raise ("ErrorBadNumber","17 is a bad number")
    return x

while True:

    def getNumber_2 ():
        try:
            getNumber ()
        except ErrorBadNumber:
            print('Write another number, please')
            getNumber ()
```

Then, it appears an error: "Undefined name 'ErrorBadNumber' ". Anyway, when I only execute the function `getNumber` the exception doesn't happen. I don't know why. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you defining a new function `getNumber_2()` inside an infinite loop?

Comment: Was the first function provided to you as-is, or is that your code? That's not a valid way to [raise an exception](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#raising-exceptions). The argument to `raise` must be an exception instance or an exception class. You're providing a tuple.

Comment: There are several issues here. Firstly, check the formatting, indentation matters. Next, this code never calls `getNumber_2()`. Then, the syntax for `raise` is `raise [Exception]` not `raise [tuple[str]]`. Lastly, `ErrorBadNumber` is never defined.

Comment: The getNumber function I copied from a book. Perhaps they did it according to the syntax of an earlier version of Python. I dont know..

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions have to be classes that derive from the base Exception class.  And i your `while` loop, you are defining a function, but you never call the function, so nothing ever runs.  It's an infinite loop, doing nothing.

For example:

```
class ErrorBadNumber(Exception):
    pass

def getNumber() :
    x = input ('Choose a number: ')
    if x != '17':      
        raise ErrorBadNumber("17 is a bad number")
    return x

while True:
    try:
        getNumber ()
        break
    except ErrorBadNumber:
        print('Write another number, please')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is true that there is no point in writing the getNumber_2 function definition inside the loop. I wanted to write just the call to that function... One question.. If we wanted to handle the exception with getNumber_2, we would place the "try-except" block that you wrote inside getNumber_2 and call it in the while. Could that be done?

Comment: Yes.  You could change `while True:` to `def getNumber_2():`, then at the end add "while True:` / `getNumber_2()`.  The issue in your original code was that you defined `getNumber_2`, but you did not call it.